# Are questions about installation or modifications of tools on topic?

Tags: discussion

Is this question well suited for GD.SE?

> How to avoid installing or remove unused libraries and assets in Adobe applications?
>
> Is there a way to install Adobe applications like Photoshop and Illustrator (either CC or Elements) so that it copies only the files needed to create or edit graphics that don't need or use the built-in libraries and assets? I'm asking because I'd like to upgrade from CS6 but I don't want to have a version of those applications that needs more disk space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe so. When I read a question like this it pertains to modifications around software and doesn't directly impact a design. Yes we have many tools in our disposal but those tools revolve around a computer environment, os versioning and modifications of additional software to meet an end goal.

Based on reading what I see, the solution you may need could be achieved with a script or a secondary application. Since our goal is to find where the best place a question like this could be answered I think that would be the Adobe forums or SuperUser. This resolves around Adobe's software and they can tell you what's best or allowed.